# Images overlapping

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to learn web development. Im making a website to practice but I cant make something work. I made a home with a background video, a burger menu and a paragraph. Now I wanted to make an images slider under the background video but i cant make it work. It just keeps overlapping with the background video. I've tried a few things but none of them actually did work. I don't know what else to do. If someone could help me i'd be very grateful. Btw i know my code sucks and it may make your eyes bleed, but im learning and trying to improve. Thanks!

HTML:

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider2');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('.next-btn');
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('.prev-btn');
const slides = document.querySelector('.slide2');
const slidesIcon = document.querySelector('.slide-icon');
const numberOfSlides = slides.length;
var slideNumber = 0; 

const menuToggle = document.querySelector('.toggle');
const showcase = document.querySelector('.showcase');

menuToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  menuToggle.classList.toggle('active');
  showcase.classList.toggle('active');
});


nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  slides.forEach((slide) => {
    slide.classList.remove('working');
  });
  slideIcons.forEach((slideIcon) => {
    slideIcon.classList.remove('working');
  });

  slideNumber++;

  if(slideNumer > (numerOfSlides - 1)) {
    slideNumber = 0;
  }

  slides[slideNumber].classList.add('working');
  slideIcons[slideNumer].classList.add('working');
});

prevBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  slides.forEach((slide) => {
    slide.classList.remove('working');
  });
  slideIcons.forEach((slideIcon) => {
    slideIcon.classList.remove('working');
  });

  slideNumber--;

  if(slideNumber < 0) {
    slideNumber = numberOfSlides - 1;
  }

  slides[slideNumber].classList.add('working');
  slideIcons[slideNumber].classList.add('working');
});

var playSlider;

var repeater = () => {
  playSlider = setInterval(() => {
    slides.forEach((slide) => {
      slide.classList.remove('working');
    });

    slideNumber++;

    if(slideNumber > (numberOfSlides - 1)) {
      slideNumber = 0;
    }

    slides[slideNumber].classList.add('working');
    slideIcons[slideNumber].classList.add('working');
  }, 4000);
}
 repeater(); 

slider2.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
  clearInterval(playSlider);
});

slider2.addEventListener('mouseout', () => {
  repeater();
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
header
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 100px;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
header .logo
{
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header .logo:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.toggle
{
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/HrfVRcx/menu.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 30px;
  background-position: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.toggle.active
{
  background: url(https://i.ibb.co/rt3HybH/close.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px;
  background-position: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.showcase
{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background: #111;
  transition: 0.5s;
  z-index: 2;
}
.showcase.active
{
  right: 300px;
}

.showcase video
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.overlay
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #03a9f4;
  mix-blend-mode: overlay;
}
.text
{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.text h2
{
  font-size: 5em;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.text h3
{
  font-size: 4em;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.text p
{
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  max-width: 700px;
}
.text a
{
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #111;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
.text a:hover
{
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
.social
{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  bottom: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.social li
{
  list-style: none;
}
.social li a
{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  filter: invert(1);
  transform: scale(0.5);
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.social li a:hover
{
  transform: scale(0.5) translateY(-15px);
}


.menu
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.menu ul
{
  position: relative;
}
.menu ul li
{
  list-style: none;
}
.menu ul li a
{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #111;
}
.menu ul li a:hover
{
  color: #03a9f4; 
}

@media (max-width: 991px)
{
  .showcase,
  .showcase header
  {
    padding: 40px;
  }
  .text h2
  {
    font-size: 3em;
  }
  .text h3
  {
    font-size: 2em;
  }
}

.slider2{
  position: relative;
  background: #000116;
  width: 800px;
  min-height: 500px;
  margin: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.slider2 .slide2{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  clip-path: circle(0% at 0 50%);
}

.slider2 .slide2.working{
  clip-path: circle(150% at 0 50%);
  transition: 2s;
}

.slider2 .slide2 img{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.slider2 .slide2.info{
  position: absolute;
  color: #222;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  width: 75%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgb(1 1 1 / 5%);
}

.slider2 .slide2 .info h2{
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.slider2 .slide2 .info p{
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.navigation{
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

.slider2:hover .navigation{
  opacity: 1;
}

.prev-btn, .next-btn{
  z-index: 999;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #222;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.prev-btn{
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.next-btn{
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
}

.navigation-visibility{
  z-index: 999;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navigation-visibility .slide-icon{
  z-index: 999;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-50px);
  margin: 0 6px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgb(1 1 1 / 20%);
}

.navigation-visibility .slide-icon.working{
  background: #4285F4;
}

@media (max-width: 900px){
  .slider2{
    width: 100%;
  }

  .slider2 .slide2 .info{
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="showcase">
  <header>
    <h2 class="logo">Testing</h2>
    <div class="toggle"></div>
  </header>
  <video src="/vid.mp4" muted loop autoplay></video>
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="text">
    <h2>Testing something</h2>
    <p>Trying to make it work</p>
    <a href="#">Gallery</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="social">
    <li><a href="" target="_blank"><img
          src="https://i.ibb.co/x7P24fL/facebook.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="" target="_blank"><img
          src="https://i.ibb.co/ySwtH4B/instagram.png"></a></li>
  </ul>
</section>

<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="slider2" id="gallery">
    <div class="slide2 working">
      <img src="./img/1.jpeg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide2">
      <img src="./img/2.jpeg" alt="">        
    </div>
    <div class="slide2">
      <img src="./img/3.jpeg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide2">
      <img src="./img/4.jpeg" alt="">   
    </div>
    <div class="slide2">
      <img src="./img/5.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide2">
      <img src="./img/6.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide2">
      <img src="./img/7.jpeg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide2">
      <img src="./img/8.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide2">
      <img src="./img/9.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide2">
      <img src="./img/10.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide2">
      <img src="./img/11.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide2">
      <img src="./img/12.jpeg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide2">
      <img src="./img/13.jpeg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="navigation">
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-left prev-btn"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-right next-btn"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation-visibility">
      <div class="slide-icon working"></div>
      <div class="slide-icon"></div>
      <div class="slide-icon"></div>
      <div class="slide-icon"></div>
      <div class="slide-icon"></div>
      <div class="slide-icon"></div>
      <div class="slide-icon"></div>
      <div class="slide-icon"></div>
      <div class="slide-icon"></div>
      <div class="slide-icon"></div>
      <div class="slide-icon"></div>
      <div class="slide-icon"></div>
      <div class="slide-icon"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please boil your code down to the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Nice choice learning web-developement, but anyway, back to the point.

**SOLUTIONS:**

- 1. Set the image/video you want to overlap to: `position: absolute;`, this overrides the other elements.
- 2. put the image/video you want to overlap after the other. Like so:

```
<!-- background-element -->
<video src="video.mov" />
<!-- Overlap element -->
<img src="example.jpg" />
```

When it all comes together, use this:

```html
<head>
<style>
.background {
position: relative;
}
.overlap {
position: absolute;
left: 50px;
}
</style>
</head>
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- background-element -->
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b4/Circle_Rufous_Solid.svg/1200px-Circle_Rufous_Solid.svg.png" class="background" width="10.5%" />
<!-- Overlap element -->
<img src="https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_24930.png" class="overlap" width="10%" />
</body>
```

Hope you understand! If you have a question, please comment.

Comment: Thank you very much. I´ll try and i´ll let you know!

Comment: No problem! I like helping people with their problems too.